# Getting to know Rust and the type system

Tags: rust, type-systems

Coming from the ML family and learned to program in SML, a very strict type system are common place.

I'm trying to learn Rust, and since I'm used to strongly typed languages an being a computer science student which are majoring in compiler theory and programming language theory. I thought that I just skipped those boring hello world intro things. I'm trying to get to know the type system with generics and lifetime in my scope at the moment.

For a simple project I'm implementing a single linked list library since I miss it and it will give me a feeling of how the type system works. I'm using reference/borrowing instead of boxing to keep thing on the stack, hence need to explicitly tell the compiler when a list node goes out of scope.

```
pub enum List<'a, L> {
    Cons(L,  &'a List<'a, L>),
    Nil,
}

impl<'a, L, S> List<'a, L> {
//          ^ unconstrained type parameter // error here
    pub fn new() -> List<'a,L> { 
        &List::Nil 
    }

    pub fn fold(f : fn(S, L) -> S, acc : S, lst : List<'a,L>) -> S {
        match lst {
            List::Cons(item, rest) => fold(f, f(acc,item), rest),
            List::Nil => acc,
        }
    }
}
```

I get that the type parameter S are unconstraint, why does it need to be, when I clearly don't want it to be constraint at all? Coming from SML and F# where this is no problem, since this can be deduced at compile time.

I know that tail recursion elimination are yet to become a feature of Rust, this is not the subject of this question.

Comment: The type parameter should be on `fold`, because it's specific to the function, not on the `impl`, i.e. `fn fold<S>`.

Comment: It's less an issue with the type system that type parameters be constrained and more a conscious decision to prevent mistakes like this. You can think of parameters as being just like arguments (to a type or function), and so should be associated to a definition. There's not a good reason to allow a type parameter to be unconstrained like this.

Answer (score 1):

Lifetimes and generics declared on an `impl` are meant to be used on the corresponding type or trait.

If you want generics on a method, you have to declare them there:

```
pub fn fold<S>(f : fn(S, L) -> S, acc : S, lst : List<'a,L>) -> S {
//         ^^^
    match lst {
        List::Cons(item, rest) => fold(f, f(acc,item), rest),
        List::Nil => acc,
    }
}
```

---

I believe one reason the compiler wants you to declare generics where there are used rather than a bigger block is that it needs to know their [variance](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/subtyping.html#variance), which depends on their usage.